# Python list splitting and sorting with similar values

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a problem where i have a list: `list1 = [[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1]]`
I want to separate the list into two different lists `ones=[]` and `zeros=[]`
except the values have to be separated corresponding to the initial list.
It would output this:

```
ones = [[1],[1,1,1]]
zeros = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0]]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this so far?

Comment: Hint: to get `ones`, you can use the `count` method to count the number of occurrences of `1` in each sublist, and multiply `[1]` by the count. Then put inside a list comprehension. Similarly for `zeros`.

Comment: I'm sorry by i dont quite understand what you mean by count method. maybe you can show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to iterate through the list, and on each list element/iterator, you need to calculate the no of times 1 and 0 occur, either by using `list.count(value)`, or you can use a temporary lists which store the one and zero and once this inner list is done add that list to the main list

```
list1 = [[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1]]
ones =[ ]
zeros = []

for i in list1:
    ones.append([1]*i.count(1))
    zeros.append([0]*i.count(0))
```

or you can do

```
list1 = [[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1]]
ones =[ ]
zeros = []

for inner_list in list1:
    tmp_zero , tmp_one = [], []
    for val in inner_list:
        if val==1:
            tmp_one.append(val)
        elif val==0:
            tmp_zero.append(val)
    ones.append(tmp_one)
    zeros.append(tmp_zero)

print(ones)
print(zeros)
```

output

```
[[1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a generator and `collections.Counter`:

```
list1 = [[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1]]

from collections import Counter
counts = map(Counter, list1)
zeros, ones = map(list, zip(*([[i]*c[i] for i in (0,1)]
                             for c in counts)))
```

Output:

```
>>> zeros
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0]]

>>> ones
[[1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```py
ones = []
zeros = []
lists = [[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1]]

for l in lists:
    ones.append([])
    zeros.append([])

    for i in l:
        if i: # i == 1
            ones[-1].append(i)
        else: # i == 0
            zeros[-1].append(i)

        count += 1

print(ones)
print(zeros)
```

Comment: answer is wrong. This is not what OP want

Comment: It'll work, but you don't need the `count` at all. Index with `[-1]` to access the last element of a list.

Comment: keep count outside the inner for loop, as it is increasing the index value and making index error. rest  as @alani said, you can access the current list in the ones/zeros with list[-1]